# C# Convert array to generic T List<>

Tags: c#, list, generics, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert an array (object[]) to a generic type T where T is a List<>

The issue here is that T is the type of the list and not the type of the items in the list. So we can't just create a List.

While I could serialize the array and deserialize it into a generic T, I don't want to use this option and would favor a faster approach to the problem.

Below is the code to test and reproduce the issue.

```
public T ConvertList<T>(object obj)
{

    if (obj is object[] objects)
    {
        var type = objects.GetType().GetElementType();
        var list = objects.Select(o => Convert.ChangeType(o, type)).ToList();

        // Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.'
        return (T)(object)list;
    }

    return default;

}

var list = ConvertList<List<string>>( new []{ "1", "a", "b" });
Assert.AreEqual(typeof(List<string>), list.GetType());
```

The issue here is that we cannot do something like :

```
var list = new List<typeof(type)>()
```

I'm open to suggestions on how we can achieve something like this.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you want `public List<T> ConvertList<T>(T[] values)`, but in that case why not just call `.ToList()` (an extension method provided by the `System.Linq` namespace)? Alternatively, change your code to accept `IList<T>`, which both array and list implement.

Comment: Your example doesn't correlate with your question. What do you exactly want to do? Can you probably rephrase or simplify the problem?

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand what you're asking for but are you basically saying you want to pass in an array of objects, have it work out what type they are and return of list of said item? So, if your object array passed in is just an array of strings and you want that array to be returned as a List<string>?

Comment: Well, `Convert.ChangeType` returns an `object`. That's why `list` is a `List<object>` and not the `List<string>` you'd like. See [covariance vs contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) on why that cast must fail. -- If you _expect_ that method to return a List, then why not make `T` really the type of the items in the list instead of the type of the whole list?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem we can use the fact that generic class `List<TElement>` implements non-generic interface `IList`. Here is how we can use this fact to solve your problem:

```
public T ConvertList<T>(object obj)
{
    if (obj is object[] objects)
    {
        // Here we create an instance of type T, where T is actually a generic
        // List<TElement>. Then we cast it to type IList. Therefore here we don't 
        // have to know and specify the type of the elements of List<TElement>.
        IList list = (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

        foreach (object o in objects)
            // Here we call IList.Add(object o). Internally it casts added
            // elements to the actual type of the elements of List<TElement>.
            list.Add(o);

        return (T) list;
    }

    return default;
}
```

Here is [complete sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KZlDVt) that shows this approach.

To use this approach you should ensure that a correct type of the `List<TElement>` is specified when calling method `ConvertList<T>`.

Comment: @user850129 Does it answer your question, do you need more details or information?